# How to Extend Scipy Sparse Matrix returned by sklearn TfIdfVectorizer to hold more features

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, sparse-matrix, scikit-learn

I am working on a text classification problem using scikit-learn classifiers and text feature extractor, particularly TfidfVectorizer class.

The problem is that I have two kinds of features, the first are captured by the n-grams obtained from TfidfVectorizer and the other are domain specific features that I extract from each document. I need to combine both features in a single feature vector for each document; to do this I need to update the scipy sparse matrix returned by TfidfVectorizer by adding a new dimension in each row holding the domain feature for this document. However, I can't find a neat way to do this, by neat I mean not converting the sparse matrix into a dense one since simply it won't fit in memory.

Probably I am missing a feature in scikit-learn or something, since I am new to both scipy and scikit-learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest would be to create a new sparse matrix with your custom features and then use `scipy.sparse.hstack` to stack the features.
You might also find the "FeatureUnion" from the pipeline module helpful.

Comment: I didn't find the "FeatureStacker", do you mean the "FeatureUnion"?

Comment: Sorry, yest, that's what I meant.